# want to add Paypal text field beside the amount field?

Tags: paypal

See this link: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ff4rjyb66

I have  written a text "i need here textfield".
So when user click on donate button, it redirect to paypal gateway and user can enter the text in a text field why they are going to donate in a textfield beside amount field?
So is it possible to add a textfield beside amount field in a paypal page?
Plz Help...
Thank You